# ServiceStack OrmLite casing a bug

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Doing a simple

```
db.Dictionary("select Id, Name from \"Product\"");
```

results in an exception

```
"column "id" does not exists"
```

The correct field name is "Id" - seems as if the Postgres in OrmLite does something to the "Id" field. Tried with some random field names with mixed casing and they also ended up in exceptions where the fields where displayed in all lower case.

Can this be achieved somehow or is this an error in OrmLite?

Is this also an issue in db.List, db.Lookup etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried putting the column in quotes to preserve the case?

```
db.Dictionary("select \"Id\", Name from \"Product\"");
```

There is a unit test example here https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite.PostgreSQL.Tests/OrmLiteSelectTests.cs#L195